# Can I deploy files from Deployer to Content Delivery server using (S)FTP?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, deployer, azure

I am trying to run a Tridion 2013 SP1 installation on Microsoft Azure using a full PaaS scenario (with Azure web apps).

At this point I am running into a rather breaking limitation while configuring the deployer server: In the `cd_storage_conf` I can only configure an absolute path (either local or UNC) for the filesystem storage, while the only way to copy files to another Azure web app is with FTP or SFTP. Does anyone know a way to work around this limitation? Any undocumented configuration options, or perhaps an extension?

By the way, I know I probably should not be using the deployer in this way (depending on filesystem storage for deplyment), but we still have some legacy components that depend on files being deployed to virtual folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOTB you won't have this. You *could* write a storage extension to deal with this, but perhaps there's something simpler/cheaper. On premise I've seen tools like RSync and robocopy being used for similar needs.

There seems to be quite a few google hits on "sftp synchronize files", maybe one of the tools there can help?

Comment: Ok, thanks! This indeed seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Technically the Deployer is part of Content Delivery, not CM. In the CM there is a Transport Service which sends published files to the Deployer and this can be configured to use FTP or SFTP or other protocols. So if you put your Deployer closer to the web app (I.e. In the Content Delivery segment) so that the Deployer can write to the same file system or DB that the web app can read, you will be fine.

If you're trying to get the Deployer to replicate/scale to multiple app servers, then what Nuno said in his answer.

Also note, support for Azure came with Web 8. IRC, Tridion 2013SP1 isn't supported on Azure. Though this doesn't mean it won't work.